# Assigning string variable to type char * in while loop in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024
int line_count = 0;

void readFile(FILE *fptr, int *line);

int main(void) {
    FILE *fptr;
    readFile(fptr, &line_count);
    return 0;
}

void readFile(FILE *fptr, int *line) {
    fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\english_words.txt", "r");
    char wordList[MAX_SIZE];
    char *englishWords[MAX_SIZE];
    
    while(fgets(wordList, MAX_SIZE, fptr) != NULL){
        char *token = strtok(wordList, "=");
        englishWords[*line] = token;
        *line += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < line_count; i++){
        //printf("%s",englishWords[i]);
    }
}
```

I need to insert the data in the token variable one by one into the englishWords array

for example:

englishWords[0] = redudancy

englishWords[1] = overlap

While doing this, I noticed a problem while debugging. The address of the token variable I put in EnglishWords never changes, so I guess all indexes are filled with the last word of the text file.

[a screenshot from the debug moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8n08.png)

Comment: Please don't tag both C++ and C when you are only using one of the two languages

Comment: `token` is a pointer to some place in the local var `wordList`. Instead of `englishWords[*line] = token;`, make a copy. See `strdup()`.

Comment: Are you using a C or a C++ compiler? The fact that you have the line `#include <cstdlib>` indicates that you are using a C++ compiler. In that case, my answer will require a slight modification, because I wrote it in C. I believe the code in my answer will not compile cleanly in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
englishWords[*line] = token;
```

you are making `englishWords[*line]` point inside the array `wordList`. However, in the next loop iteration, you overwrite the content of `wordList`. Therefore, you are probably also overwriting what the pointer from the previous loop iteration is pointing to. This is not what you want.

Therefore, you should instead make a copy of the token, which will not be overwritten, and make `englishWords[*line]` point to that copy.

In order to make a copy of a string, you can use [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) to allocate memory for the copy of the string, and then use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to actually copy it. Some platforms provide the function [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) which combines both of these function calls in one function call.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024
int line_count = 0;

void readFile(FILE *fptr, int *line);

int main(void) {
    FILE *fptr;
    readFile(fptr, &line_count);
    return 0;
}

void readFile(FILE *fptr, int *line) {
    fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\english_words.txt", "r");
    char wordList[MAX_SIZE];
    char *englishWords[MAX_SIZE];
    
    while(fgets(wordList, MAX_SIZE, fptr) != NULL){
        char *token = strtok(wordList, "=");

        //allocate memory for the copy of the string
        englishWords[*line] = malloc( strlen(token) + 1 );
        if ( englishWords[*line] == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //actually copy the string
        strcpy( englishWords[*line], token );

        *line += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < line_count; i++){
        //printf("%s",englishWords[i]);
    }

    //cleanup

    //free allocated memory
    for ( int i = 0; i < *line; i++ )
    {
        free( englishWords[i] );
    }

    //close the file
    fclose( fptr );
}
```